# Can't resolve ReasonReact.js in webpack

Tags: webpack, reason, bucklescript, reason-react

I'm trying to get ReasonML working with an existing React code base. I'm not using `create-react-app`. This is a `hand-built` project. For the most part, it looks like everything is set up fine. However, I'm getting an error when I try to run Webpack with the default compiled `bs.js` files.

```
Error: Can't resolve '../lib/js/src/ReasonReact.js'
```

My `bsconfig.js` is almost directly copy/pasted from the ReasonML docs:

```
{
  "name": "reason-react",
  "reason": {"react-jsx" : 2},
  "sources": ["src"],
  "package-specs": [{
    "module": "commonjs",
    "in-source": true
  }],
  "suffix": ".bs.js",
  "namespace": true,
  "bs-dependencies": ["reason-react"],
  "refmt": 3
}
```

Bucklescript is generating the appropriate `bs.js` files in the location where I'd expect them. All well and good. However, I'm not surprised that Webpack can't find what it's looking for. There is no `/lib/js/src/ReasonReact.js` file. There's a `ReasonReact.js` file in `/lib/bs`, and one in `node_modules/reason-react/lib/js`.

When I edit the compiled ReasonML files, and point the ReasonReact variable to the `node_modules` `ReasonReact.js` file, everything works.

I've looked over several tutorials and articles. Maybe I've missed something, but I can't find anything about the error I'm encountering. Does anyone have any ideas as to why the pathing would be off in the compiled `bs.js` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have named your project `reason-react`. In combination with having `namespace` turned on, this creates a local namespace module called `ReasonReact` which interferes with module resolution of the dependency.

You could probably fix this just by setting `namespace` to `false` in `bsconfig.json`, since it doesn't sound like you are making a library that is going to be consumed by others and therefore don't need namespacing anyway. But you should also avoid using the same name as one of your dependencies since it so easily causes confusing issues like this.

Remember to change the name in both `bsconfig.json` and `package.json` to avoid issues.